# Enable FreeType in PHP 7.1

Tags: php, macos, freetype

i have on my mac with macOS 10.13.6, php version 7.1.16 and i need to install and enable FreeType module for gd.
I tried install it with brew like

> brew install freetype

and

> brew install gd --with-freetype

but still no effect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRWYc.png)

Comment: This is so old! If you're still with this problem, you need to generate `gd.so` and use it as an extension in `php.ini`.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSalazarMori how? como hiciste eso? I cant install freetype support on my native php terminal.

Comment: There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708542/7208109), but you have to translate to MacOS, because it's in Linux Azure Server. I don't know nothing about MacOS, but it is the same problem.