# Shifting from App Services to a Docker container due to file persistence?

Tags: php, azure, docker, apache, azure-web-app-service

While connected to my App Service (vanilla PHP 7.4 App Service) through SSH, I can see:

`Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted`

If my `php.ini` and `apache2.conf` reside outside of `/home`, I'll never be able to have changes to these files persisted correct? IIRC, I can't modify `apache2.conf` to set another location for `php.ini` within `/home`, the Apache configuration change will never persist the Apache restart.

This only means that I need to build a docker container to have full control of my settings? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#customize-php_ini_system-directives

Comment: Ahhhh,.. .htaccess, wouldn't have crossed my mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @[CSharpRocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793891/csharprocks) posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members for similar issue.

Based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#customize-php_ini_system-directives):

> - To **Customize PHP_INI_SYSTEM** directives  we can't use the  **`_.htaccess_`**  approach. App Service provides a separate  mechanism using the  `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR`  app setting.  First, run the
>   following command in the  Cloud Shell  to add an app setting called
>   `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` .
>
> > ```
> > az webapp config appsettings set --name <app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --settings PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR="/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:/home/site/ini"
> > ```
>
> For example if want to  change the value of [expose_php](https://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php)  run
> the following commands:
>
> ```
>     cd /home/site
>     mkdir ini
>     echo "expose_php = Off" >> ini/setting.ini
> ```

For more information please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918752/azure-app-service-linux-php-how-to-add-with-freetype-dir-usr-lib-x86-64-li)